# Turning a negative (-) into a normal number

Tags: javascript

So I have two variables which when one is divided by the other will give me a negative number

-1, -2, -3

...and so on.

What I need is to get this, let's say, -2 into a variable which is 2 not -2

How can one achieve this?

This is my code to come up with the - value:

```
var slideNumberOn = (left_indent / divWidth);
```

i found something like the below but it does not work:

```
var slideNumberOn = (left_indent / divWidth);
var slideNumberOnNoMinus = slideNumberOn.replace('-',"");
```

Comment: `slideNumberOn = -slideNumberOn` ?

Comment: Removed the [tag:jquery] tag. Really has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

Absolute value.

```
Math.abs(-2) // 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Its just math, multiply times -1.

```
if (slideNumberOn < 0)
    slideNumberOn = slideNumberOn * -1;
```

Comment: or -slideNumberOn or use the absolute value function. You have a few options.

Answer (score 3):

a more maths orientated answer but no more correct is to multiply by -1,

```
var newnumber = -2 * -1
```

Comment: perfect, was never any good at maths

Answer (score 2):

```
var slideNumberOn = (left_indent / divWidth);
var slideNumberOnNoMinus = -slideNumberOn;
```

Or, more succinctly,

```
var slideNumberOn = -(left_indent / divWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [abs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp) i think

```
var slideNumberOn = Math.abs(left_indent / divWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Math.abs(number)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs):

```
var result = Math.abs(slideNumberOn);
```